# Criação de um banco de dados para cada usuário

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou montando um sistema de vendas web com `php` e `mysql`, onde teremos várias empresas cadastradas, sendo cada empresa um usário que irá controlar suas vendas.
Nossa equipe está com uma dúvida: criar um `banco de dados` para cada usuário, ou criar apenas um `banco de dados` geral e as tabelas terem a coluna com o id do usuário para executar os cadastros e consultas pertinentes ao usuário?
Alguma das opções retorna maior desempenho nos selects do banco?
Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada opção?

Comment: Informe mais detalhes. Exemplo, se cada empresa é uma loja independente uma da outra, imagino que cada loja terá produtos diferentes. Esses produtos são acessíveis por um único shopping mall ou são acessíveis de forma independente?

Comment: Sim, cada cliente seria uma loja independente, com produtos diferentes, sem a possibilidade de relação uma com a outra, tudo de forma independente. A intenção é ter diversos pequenos clientes, de preferência se tudo der certo, milhares de clientes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Depende da escala ou volume

Tudo depende da escala do produto. Quando a escala aumenta, muitas decisões de projeto são contra-intuitivas.

Por escala não me refiro apenas ao volume de dados. E escala e volume  dependem do contexto.

Do ponto de vista de desempenho, um volume razoável seria talvez na casa dos milhões de registros. Eu já trabalhei em sistemas que processavam centenas de milhares de registros sem dificuldade alguma, obviamente com as devidas otimizações. Se cada cliente tiver os seus milhões de registros, então colocar tudo numa mesma tabela pode ser um problema.

Entretanto, do ponto de vista do negócio, depende de quem serão os clientes, do quanto o produto pretende ser evoluído, dos procedimentos que serão adotados para desenvolvimento e manutenção, ter os dados num banco de dados pode ser totalmente desejado ou totalmente impossível.

O plano é vender o sistema para algumas poucas empresas e então é esperado que a demanda de cada empresa para manutenção e evolução seja grande? Ou seria vender o sistema como um SaaS para uma massa de pequenas empresas sem que elas tenham um acesso mais avançado (pense no Mercado Livre, por exemplo)?

## Problemas com um banco de dados compartilhado

Vamos pensar em alguns cenários com um único banco:

- Você precisa fazer backup, todos os clientes ficam lentos por causa disso
- Um cliente apaga dados sem querer e solicita a restauração de um backup (não queria estar na pele do responsável por isso)
- Erros na aplicação fazem com que dados de um cliente apareçam para outro ou, pior ainda, dados são atualizados sem um filtro adequado no `WHERE`.
- Você precisa atualizar a aplicação e a nova versão altera a estrutura dos dados. Você necessariamente precisa atualizar o sistema para todos os clientes, tudo ou nada. É uma prática comum em empresas sérias lançar atualizações primeira para um subconjunto dos clientes e depois, se tudo correr bem, atualizar os demais. Isso seria impossível.
- Sua empresa vende o sistema para diferentes ao redor do mundo. A partir de um momento decide-se que para melhorar o desempenho em outros países ou ainda para se adequar a legislação vigente o sistema tem que hospedar os dados naquele país. Se o banco de dados fosse separado, bastaria mover o banco para uma máquina virtual num data center daquele país e também colocar uma instância da aplicação lá. Mas agora você terá que extrair dados de um banco compartilhado e colocar em outro vazio.
- Se houver muito uso por um cliente, isso pode atrapalhar os demais. Por exemplo, um grande cliente executa uma rotina que importa um milhão de registros. Outros clientes que estejam querendo ler/gravar na mesma tabela irão ser afetados.
- Geração de ids e chaves será mais complexa e/ou menos intuitiva, já que dois registros com ids consecutivos podem pertencer a clientes completamente diferentes.
- Todas as consultas do sistema e todos os métodos de acesso ao banco de dados vão precisar de um parâmetro extra. Os objetos de domínio e praticamente todo o sistema seria poluídos pelo *tenant id* pra lá e pra cá.

## Vantagens de bancos de dados separados

- Fazer e restaurar backups é trivial
- Suporte não enlouquece para investigar um problema de perda/corrupção de dados
- Diferentes clientes podem estar em diferentes versões do sistema
- Instâncias do sistema podem estar espalhadas ao redor do mundo e movidas conforme necessário
- Uso intenso, deadlocks e outros problemas relacionados ao banco que ocorrerem em um cliente não afetam os demais

## Dificuldades de manter vários bancos

O grande problema de um banco para cada cliente é manter a estrita organização das alterações no banco de dados devidamente relacionadas com cada versão do sistema.

Linguagens como PHP onde é fácil você simplesmente sobrescrever um arquivo em produção devem ter cuidados redobrados.

Primeiro, use uma biblioteca de migrações para que o seu sistema tenha a capacidade de sempre atualizar o banco de dados automaticamente e garantir que a estrutura é consistente com aquela versão. Isso pode dar um pouco mais de trabalho no começo, mas se paga (muito bem, diga-se de passagem) com o tempo, principalmente em projetos que evoluem constantemente.

Segundo, tenha sempre um controle forte das versões do sistema relacionadas com o seu repositório de código. Por exemplo, cada versão do sistema que for para produção deve ter uma tag correspondente no Git. Assim quando qualquer problema ocorrer você consegue facilmente juntar o banco de dados e aquela versão específica e reproduzir quaisquer erros.

Answer (score 5):

Você provavelmente não irá notar qualquer diferença no desempenho do banco a não ser que você possua milhões de clientes.

Algumas vantagens de aplicar esse método seriam:

1. Modelo de banco mais simples;
2. Mais fácil de exportar e fazer backup de dados de um usuário específico;
3. Quando ocorre alguma alteração, problema ou manutenção apenas os usuários envolvidos são afetados;
4. Dessa forma é mais fácil desviar recursos caso algum usuário específico necessite;
5. Facilidade de expansão do banco, já que é simples separar alguns usuários e colocar em um segundo servidor. Isso também é mais econômico, sendo que é mais barato comprar novos servidores do que fazer upgrade em um existente na maioria dos casos.

Desvantagens:

1. Se tiver alguma alteração que precise ser realizada em todos os usuários vai ser bem complicado.
2. Consideravelmente complicado de criar e manter, principalmente para deixar organizado, versionamento de cada banco, log de alterações...

A lista de vantagens pode ser maior, mas na maioria dos casos não vale a dor de cabeça que isso pode causar, aconselho a pensar bem antes de implementar.

Para mais informações acesse [esse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) artigo feito pela Microsoft sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que o maior vilão em termos de desempenho é o servidor, e não propriamente o modo como é estruturado o(s) banco de dados.

Independente do volume de dados gerado por cada cliente, há que se levar em conta o volume de acessos ao servidor, principalmente os acessos simultâneos. Se o servidor não for capaz de atender à demanda de acessos, o desempenho final será insatisfatório em qualquer dos casos.

Para dar um exemplo prático, atualmente mantenho um sistema que possui cerca de 10.000 clientes e mais de 35.000 pedidos contendo em média dois a três produtos; um único banco de dados, referenciando clientes, produtos e pedidos através de seus respectivos IDs; a consulta de histórico mais complexa do sistema, envolvendo todas as tabelas, não ultrapassa 15 segundos.